# Requesting a cURL GET Request in PHP outputs garbage

Tags: php, curl, microsoft-dynamics, php-curl

I'm trying to build a Connector to Dynamics 365 Business Central but I'm having problems getting the data.  Please help me figure out why when I send a GET request using cURL and PHP, it produces the following output:

�S[O�0�+(��&��qB��i�t�F/���=�ا��Ďb�}N�"&�M�����������8�0% �;

Here is my code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/{tenantID}/customers/?$filter=displayName%20eq%20'Shawn%20Test'",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: {Auth Code}"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: This is an encoding problem, try to remove CURLOPT_ENCODING line from your request or try to choose different encoding from your browser

Comment: What is the endpoint supposed to return? This looks a lot like you're receiving some kind of binary data from the endpoint.

Comment: Thanks @Bakly!  Removing CURLOPT_ENCODING fixed it.  I got this from Postman and it came with the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a character encoding issue, or maybe you are receiving binary data.

What is this endpoint supposed to return? Check the response headers, it might give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an encoding problem, try to remove CURLOPT_ENCODING line from your request or try to choose different encoding from your browser